# How can I install packages I have already downloaded using terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, deb

I have some packages in `.deb` format like: google-chrome, teamviewer, brackets and so on that I have downloaded.

My Internet connection is slow, so I need to avoid downloading them again if possible.

I want to install these packages by a command line method, because Ubuntu Software seems unable to install them.

Comment: Double click on the Deb file and that's how you do it.

Comment: I recommend [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/527764) from the linked post

Comment: @user68186 how to double click `using terminal`?^

Answer (score 0):

At the command line, you can install `.deb` files with:

`sudo dpkg -i <file>`

Comment: <file> must be where ?

Comment: You've indicated you "have some packages by format(deb)" ... those are the files.

Comment: @rateb to run this command, the file must be in the current working directory, or you can specify the exact path to it. But please see the linked duplicate for better methods, specifically you can now use APT which performs dependency resolution